# Error message from calendar program

Tags: calendar

When I log into my computer I get this message from my calendar program:

```
The server responded with an error.
The request for account "iCloud "failed.
The server responded with "412" to operation
CalDAVCalendarSplitDualTypeCalendarQueueableOPeration.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you give more details such as what model your Mac is (iMac, MacBook, MacBook Air, MacBook Pro or Mac Mini), the official "Apple Subfamily" designation (e.g. Retina, 13 inch, Late 2014) or its model identifier (e.g. MacBook Air 6,2), and your software version (e.g. OS X El Capitan v10.11.4). Also, what calendar program are you using?

Comment: @brick Don't think that the model of the Mac is important here. What would help to dig deeper is OSX version, application used and where the message is coming from (doesn't look like an error popup, is this from a log file). Also, does the error occur regularly? And if there are several calendars configured for the account: Does it also occur if one (or all of them) are disabled?

Answer (score 1):

I just got off the phone with support and now it's fixed. This is what we did:

1. System Preferences - > Internet Accounts
2. Select the iCloud account.
3. Uncheck "Calendars"
4. Open a Finder Window.
5. Go to the ~/Library folder. (He had me click on the Go menu and press the Option key in order to display the Library and then go to it from there.)
6. Copy ~/Library/Calendars onto the desktop, then delete the on the one in the ~/Library folder.
7. Restart.
8. System Preferences - > Internet Accounts
9. Select the iCloud account.
10. Check "Calendars"
11. Open the Calendars app. Wait for all the calendars and events to reload from the cloud.

That's it. Test by trying to make or edit events. If all is well, delete the back-up.